# Changes in values will not be reflected outside of function

Tags: javascript, typescript, deque

When I change values of `front` and `back` inside of `frontAndBackExist` function, the changes won't be reflected outside of `frontAndBackExist` function. Thus when I call `isEmpty` function after adding and removing nodes, it returns false even though there aren't any nodes left. Is this because `front` and `back` are primitive values?

```
type DequeNode = {
  value: any;
  prev?: DequeNode;
  next?: DequeNode;
};
type FrontBackTypes = DequeNode | undefined;

function Deque() {
  let front: FrontBackTypes = undefined;
  let back: FrontBackTypes = undefined;
  let cnt = 0;

  function addFront(value: any) {
    if (!front) {
      front = back = { value };
      cnt++;
      return null;
    }
    cnt++; // a new node just pushed!
    const tempFront = front;
    front = { value, prev: tempFront };
    tempFront.next = front;
    return;
  }

  function removeFront() {
    if (!front) {
      return null;
    }
    const value = peekFront();
    if (frontAndBackExist(front, back)) {
      front = undefined;
      back = undefined;
      cnt--;
      return value;
    }
    cnt--;
    front = front.prev;
    delete front!.next;
    return value;
  }

  function peekFront() {
    return front?.value;
  }

  function addBack(value: any) {
    if (!front) {
      const backVal = { value };
      front = backVal;
      back = backVal;
      cnt++;
      return null;
    }
    cnt++;
    const tempBack = back;
    back = { value, next: tempBack };
    tempBack!.prev = back;
    return;
  }

  function removeBack() {
    if (!back) {
      return null;
    }

    const value = peekBack();

    if (frontAndBackExist(front, back)) {
      front = undefined;
      back = undefined;
      cnt--;
      return value;
    }
    cnt--;
    back = back.next;
    delete back!.prev;
    return value;
  }

  function peekBack() {
    return back?.value;
  }

  function size() {
    return cnt;
  }

  function isEmpty() {
    return cnt === 0;
  }

  function clear() {
    front = undefined;
    back = undefined;
    cnt = 0;
  }

  function frontAndBackExist(front: FrontBackTypes, back: FrontBackTypes) {
    return front === back;
    // if (front === back) {
    //   // if you change front and back value here, it won't be reflected outside of this function. thus the last isEmpty call returns false even though there is no node in deque.
    //   front = undefined;
    //   back = undefined;
    //   return true;
    // } else {
    //   return false;
    // }
  }

  return {
    addFront,
    removeFront,
    peekFront,
    addBack,
    removeBack,
    peekBack,
    size,
    isEmpty,
    clear,
  };
}

const deque = Deque();
console.log(deque.peekFront()); // undefined
console.log(deque.isEmpty(), "return if deque is empty or not");
console.log(deque.size(), "return length of deque");
deque.addFront(1);
console.log(deque.peekBack()); // 1
deque.addFront(2);
console.log(deque.size(), "return length of deque");
deque.clear();
console.log(deque.size(), "return length of deque");
console.log(deque.removeBack()); // 1
console.log(deque.isEmpty(), "return if deque is empty or not");
deque.addFront(3);
deque.addFront(4);
console.log(deque.size(), "return length of deque");
console.log(deque.size());
console.log(deque.peekBack()); // 2
deque.addBack(5);
deque.addBack(6);
console.log(deque.peekBack()); // 6
console.log(deque.removeFront()); // 4
console.log(deque.removeFront()); // 3
console.log(deque.removeFront()); // 2
console.log(deque.size(), "return length of deque");
console.log(deque.removeFront()); // 5
console.log(deque.isEmpty(), "return if deque is empty or not");
console.log(deque.removeFront()); // 6
console.log(deque.isEmpty(), "return if deque is empty or not");
console.log(deque.removeFront()); // undefined
console.log(deque.isEmpty(), "return if deque is empty or not");
```

Change `front` and `back` values inside helper function but those changes won't be reflected outside of the helper function.

Comment: *Reassigning* variables never affects the contents of the previous value assigned to the variable, whether it was primitive or not.  Why not just access `front` and `back` via a closure, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzXDm)?  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer, if you'd let me help clean up the question (there are some distracting unrelated errors in your code).  If not, what am I missing?  Also, is there a reason you're doing it this way instead of via a `class`?

Comment: @Bergi at the very end, I call `deque.isEmpty()` and there is still node which should not be the case.

Comment: @jcalz inside `frontAndBackExist`, I assign undefined to both front and back but they never become undefined I guess.  Yes, please write up an answer if possible at all. I am still interested to know what is the best way to implement `clean` function. I am using `factory function` because there is already a pretty good deque implementation using `Class` and did not want to just copy and paste it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74831093/15156010

Comment: I'm confused, what is the use case for rewriting a class into a non-class factory function?  I guess it doesn't matter, but I don't understand why you wouldn't want to copy and paste something that works (especially if your attempts to alter it made it no longer work).

Comment: @jcalz Sorry about asking a few questions in one post. There are pros and cons of using `class` vs `factory-function` https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e

Comment: @jcalz using closure the way you did, this problem has been fixed. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with code like

```
function frontAndBackExist(front: FrontBackTypes, back: FrontBackTypes) {
  if (front === back) {
    front = undefined;
    back = undefined;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

is that `front` and `back` are [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter) to the function, and are thus [local variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Local_variable) inside the function body.  So these variables only exist in the function [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

When you assign `front = undefined` or `back = undefined`, all you are doing is assigning new values to these local variables, inside the function.  It has no effect on whatever values were passed in as *arguments* to the function.  JavaScript does **not** evaluate function calls by [passing references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) to its arguments.

And the fact that you had some variables in an outer scope named `front` and `back` doesn't affect things; your function parameters are merely *shadowing* the same-named variables (see [What is "Shadow Identifier Declaration" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42174100/2887218)) and therefore *preventing* your access of them inside the function.

---

JavaScript evaluates function calls by [sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), which is essentially the same as [copying the value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) of the argument to the parameter, but with the wrinkle that *objects are essentially references*.  When you call a function with a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) argument, you are getting a copy of a primitive value.  But when you call a function with an object as its argument, you are getting *a copy of the object reference*.  So while *reassigning* the parameter's value has no external effects:

```
function foo(fb: FrontBackTypes) {
  fb = { value: 1 };
}
const x = { value: 0 };
console.log(x.value) // 0
foo(x);
console.log(x.value) // 0, unchanged
```

you can have external effects if you don't reassign the parameter but instead act on its members:

```
function foo(fb: FrontBackTypes) {
  if (fb) {
    fb.value = 1;
  }
}
const x = { value: 0 };
console.log(x.value) // 0
foo(x);
console.log(x.value) // 1, changed
```

So, one way you could fix your code is to refactor so `front` and `back` are members of an object and then pass that object as a function parameter.  But this isn't how I'd recommend proceeding.

---

Instead, I'd suggest making `frontAndBackExist()` a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with no parameters.  You can access the external `front` and `back` variables inside such a closure because they were defined in an outer scope.  That is, just stop shadowing `front` and `back`:

```
function frontAndBackExist() {
  if (front === back) {
    front = undefined;
    back = undefined;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now in the rest of your code, just call `frontAndBackExist()` with no arguments (and you don't have to write `front = undefined; back = undefined;` out there either):

```
function removeFront() {
  if (!front) {
    return null;
  }
  const value = peekFront();
  if (frontAndBackExist()) {
    cnt--;
    return value;
  }
  cnt--;
  front = front.prev;
  delete front!.next;
  return value;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhCOBXCA5A9gE2gXigbwFgAoKKANwEMAbZALigoDsQBuY0sAJwjIH564SVJghsSURhAAewfrATJ0WMQF8xoSFABinNI2AAhCgGMA1gBVwEAM5RcgxSKgAfKIkZYAZgEtJGMcSMFAC2NmAm0AAKFNbWBiAAygAWFJy+AOb47BIhYRGwaDaMaMAAwimM6dCE4qSe7sbA3npQnmhoABSeAEb0OnqGJhZW1gCUWbWkUN6eUF3d4zVTy63dAHSUNDhQAIxiK1Aq2aRHk8Z61sBQUnb45NR0UAAMh-tT54zWaFQQa1Ro6Q6Ug2Dwg4wA9ODnsdWu0gaM3qQPl8fn8AUCQVsIVCdtlTtkgqFrOFjNAYIVrMUyhUqhMYfVGI1moxYZ0en1dPojGZLJAxhMDj1bnh7lt6DtXjDTstkVcbrgRZtHi81DDkd9fv9AcClWCoJDoZM2p0pAi1RcNWjtZjkNjDXjiPiiAymS0HBAOotsj8rp5OcAOQNucM+bd3F5fBB-N6IFdukNA1yhrybGGPBAfH43j6oMZ9LcngFxC6mi0KBgMP19B1dfQmCAvZMZnMAIR+gaNwX+27xszC0XISWTJH6ADUo8RU24wEQnBZjEQVCok+l7zHE-1UIoEggAHcJE4AFaIS5QMAnpJRlvmz5XYAQYJgKtXXDt-STt8vu66gA0Z+4ZD0Pej7PkOyzAU+-prJIMi3J+k7TrOjBvE6dQNKWLLcMEaBkBAz6egKUzNh0bb+p2KyIXOEiLsuUo3qeuq3JAECmPhZpNrMXT+gAgh4wYAKJSN4lyeuRMr6AAtBJk6kJRLK6iuaqSdJ9Ldq+UFcDwk5YD60Cfi20HSMACGxkhA6iA6RDZCWzJnhALFsYRsmmVRn68DaFniKhrTobZ5YYMGNagnWzBidMnGkR2TnvBccZDAAatQ-aMaqw6tGpUC9qYiW0WlWU9gl1Aybm67FXJ1FLopZylfRd4PmAwYFWYk75Qq5l-jBAZQBBjWpeB9XBgZmlkE1pgmTOc4ocQ1m+S0WE4RAgVhcRLZZWFzkTfONFVbV5lMfZphLUWyzEZ+vEBUMgnCcAonRSOwBSWVLnyaCVXiQ9KmTK1mVDIZMjaRAuk-WYQ0AeNZkKZZM2MhhdksUt0XlVl7mQ1503FrNLLWN4ABeHpheVebGVDGMw7Zwn8Y+oAEUsU7PSVL7YLghYk2hZMtMYPypDTqkDGmEZZjC33hhmkbRtVX4s2jVmk66LJnXxl1CSJy2cZ+dhM8DpjrelfO4CLmZRsVwvpob4sHOVwCcMgK5QID1jVDCG1mZ41AO29hzo87VG06Q-nPj+MLzbhAcwsxrH+oHkz+cGUfLMHi1DHHUzh7HMLY3jyekBTVMgFnuZc5wyepU6spQFgQi3O6npiOqqJah0FfIGs4dsQim5uKbYvEHXmrok3vw52A1OjH+ABE5XNgP0y2PVoBQGgnAHsAY-sb3VqNwovwZ-j4-lT8lTAEkC+zAPq9iAPaz+-6HQ7GvFr1-3W8twdS3twauJEJf18DB0ABM99PiWgbpfHeno970wPukI+J9y5b3PsQS+nMIDc0ASiPugJQG413lACekCICH2PmgU+8C0HAKfkINYCc34sA7p-deIDn5DxHhAza4U4GV2EnbXOC8l5UgQV-Z+P9qwAGZ2LfwrPhAALGQx+mDn5gNHrg-eBDoFEJIUIARDCKHN0UbIjBm9KGpyGKJWhBo-6IKERWQKABWcRViLpmA6AANn0RvS+xinGjHflCZxPcH4GMvgnNuZioRSP8UAuRhjm7BJvt40JUARERPQe45+sTf7xI7hYog2j5GUMUawsyUCYHEI4cgLRATUmUPSdWTJBobHJPIXk5uzCQDgOUfTKeW8Z7cOHiAXhy8KmRMCWkh8C0Qkdz8TkypjDKGtPaXgthXTOGzx4YvQZbjZkxLGSHOJPjO4CyjI0qJl95lKMWWZZZg4uFz36es-h7EgA)